# What does the expression $1^n$ mean as a function argument?

Tags: notation

In a [paper about predicate encryption or attribute based encryption](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/ec08.pdf), the setup function is mentioned with the $setup(1^n)$ or $setup(1^l)$. I want to know what is meant here.

Is it multiples of ones or representing something else?
Also, why is this used here?

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/ec08.pdf

Comment: If you want to understand why the $1^n$ is there and what purpose it solves, see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8174/351.

Answer (score 5):

If you got an expression that resembles $\{1\}^n$ (or $1^n$) at a place in a surrounding expression where you would expect an $n$-bit bit string to be, the $\{1\}^n$ expression means a string of $n$ bits each with the bit value $1$.

Conversely, $\{0\}^n$ means a string of $n$ zero valued bits, and $\{0,1\}^n$ just means any bit string of length $n$.

In the paper you mentioned, it looks like $n$ plays double duty: it both determines the set of attributes/predicates, and it is the security parameter. In this case the authors don't seem to use this notation to indicate that the setup is polynomial in the binary logarithm of the key space, but rather that it is polynomial in the maximum number of independent predicates.

The concepts Predicate and Attribute are related in such way that each entity $k$ (that might or might not have rights to decrypt a given cipher text) is associated with some set of predicates $F_k = \{f_i\}$ and the cipher text is associated with an Attribute $I$, and entity $k$ will be able to decrypt the cipher text if and only if $f_i(I)=1$ for some predicate $f_i \in F_k$ the entity has been assigned. The attribute was set as parameter when the plain text was encrypted to produce the cipher text.

The $Setup$ function defined in the [referenced paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/papers/ec08.pdf) generates a master public key $PK$ and a master secret key $SK$. The master secret key is then passed to the $GenKey$ function that generates a secret key $SK_f$ for each predicate $f$

Although not written out explicitly, I suppose the argument of the Setup function could be interpreted as the union of the unhidden attributes of the cipher texts that the master secret key (generated by setup), will decrypt. With $n$ predicates, there are $2^n$ possible valid attribute value classes (there might be more than one value that instantiates each attribute), meaning that the set of attributes is isomorphic to $\{0,1\}^n$. One might in such case define the isomorphism $\phi$ such that the master attribute $I_M = \phi(1^n)$ equals the attribute such that $f_k(I_M) = 1$ for all predicates $f_k, 0 \le k \lt n$.

So how does this relate to the specific definitions in the referenced paper?

For starters, the set of attributes $\Sigma = \mathbb Z^n_N$ is a vector set with $N^n$ different values. However, the difference between $N^n$ and $2^n$ is due to there being $(N-1)^{n-k}$ different values in $\Sigma$ that all correspond to the same selection of $k$ predicates. Think of it like this:

Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb Z_N$, where each row corresponds to a predicate vector. Let $Y$ be an $n$ element column matrix corresponding to an attribute $I$. Let $XY = Z$. Now, since matrix multiplication of a row on the left with a column on the right corresponds to a dot vector multiplication, for each element $z_i$ in the $Z$ column matrix, $f_i(I) = 0 \iff z_i = 0$. On the other hand, if $f_i(I) \neq 0$, then $z_i$ might be *any* non-zero value in $\mathbb Z_N$, and there are $N-1$ such values.

Comment: I added some clarification on why this is used. Feel free to revert if you think it doesn't fit your answer, then I'll post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Thanks, the link wasn't available when I wrote my first reply. FWIW the definitions only mention that the same security parameter is also an implicit parameter of the set of attributes and set of predicates. On what page did you find the reference to polynomial time setup?

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the paper at all (being a bit on limited time), I just remember that usage convention from other papers. All "normal" (not brute-force) algorithms used in Cryptography are somehow supposed to be polynomial-time (or probabilistic polynomial).

Comment: Henrick, your answer sounds plausible on the surface, but when I read the paper, it's pretty clear that it is not correct.  The real story is that $1^n$ is a security parameter (as the paper states in Definition 1), not some representation of hidden predicates, and the real explanation is the one given at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8174/351

Comment: @D.W.: There is more to it. The parameter $n$ is not just an empty place holder that only exists in the security parameter $1^n$, but represents the number of dimensions in the formal attribute set $\mathbb Z_N^n$. Confer page 3.

Comment: @HenrickHellström, thanks, I see what you mean about more going on here.  I still don't think this answer is quite right, though.  The set of attributes is $Z_N^n$, where $N$ is a large integer; thus, there are $N^n$ possible attribute values, not $2^n$.  There is no reason why $1^n=(1,1,\dots,1)$ would be a particularly special or interesting attribute value.  Therefore, I believe that $1^n$ is passed to the Setup routine for the reasons in my answer (force it to be polytime in $n$), not anything to do with representing the set of all predicates/attributes.

Comment: @D.W.: Unless my math is completely off, there can't be $N^n$ possible disjoint attribute values, due to the way the predicates and attributes are combined, using a dot vector product in $\mathbb Z_N$. If the dot vector product evaluates to $0$, the predicate is "included" in the attribute. Assuming both attribute hiding and information theoretic security, the number of independent predicates and attributes are bounded by the number of linear equations that would be required to solve unknown predicates, which is $n$.

Comment: @HenrickHellström, maybe I'd better narrow my comments.  As a simple starter, the answer claims "there are $2^n$ possible attribute values", but this does not appear to be correct.  It appears there are $N^n$ possible attribute values (as the set of attributes is $Z_N^n$); certainly it's a lot more than $2^n$.  (OK, the attribute $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ might be equivalent to $(2a_1,\dots,2a_n)$, but even then there would still be at least $N^{n-1}$ non-equivalent attribute values.)

Comment: @D.W.: I think we should make a distinction between "valid attributes" and "numerically possible attribute values". I meant the former, istm you mean the latter. My point is that if you accept more than $2^n$ different attributes as valid in the sense that you accept more than $n$ predicates, you still can't use the numerical methods outlined in the paper for selecting attributes that combine more than $n$ predicates at a time - you will end up with an overdetermined equation system if you try to select an attribute for $n+1$ predicates.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8572/discussion-between-henrick-hellstrom-and-d-w)