# What is here the security parameter $1^\kappa$?

Tags: rsa

Let it be $K$ a key generation algorithm  which takes $(k,d)$ as input with $k$ as the bit length for $n=pq$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{P}$ and $d=|p-q|$ as the minimum distance between $p$ and $q$ (RSA). What would be the security parameter $1^\kappa$?

Would it be $\kappa=k+d$ or only $\kappa=k$ and if it were the case on what would it depends?

I searched the following links and could not find an answer to my question:

[What does the expression $1^n$ mean as a function argument?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/what-does-the-expression-1n-mean-as-a-function-argument/7853#7853)
[Why does key generation take an input $1^k$, and how do I represent it in practice?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/why-does-key-generation-take-an-input-1k-and-how-do-i-represent-it-in-practi/8199#8199)

Comment: For RSA key generation per [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62), $k$ could be $3072$ (for security comparable to a 128-bit symmetric key), and $d$ could be $2^{k/2-100}=2^{1436}$. Adding such wildly different quantities makes no sense. Also $d$ has a standard meaning in RSA. What about $|p-q|>2^δ$? Independently: I know no mathematically justified reason why enforcing a minimum $|p-q|$ in RSA key generation would improve security comparing to not doing so. And over-increasing $δ$ (say to $8n/9$) _decreases_ security. So why would $κ=k+δ$ make sense?

Comment: The question if this makes sense or what other security requirements would be I especially asked in another post. But it may be, for example, that someone starts with $int(\sqrt(n))$ when bruteforcing the factorization of $n$. Then such a distance would probably make sense. The question at this point would be whether it affects the definition of $\kappa$.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons in [my comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/205033) I'll asume we change the question to define $δ$ with $2^\delta<\lvert p-q\rvert$, and $\kappa=k+\delta$. [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62) key generation would for example use $k=3072$ and $\delta=k/2-100=1436$.

I can't find any reference discussing asymptotic RSA security with a notation like $1^k$ that specify a minimum $\lvert p-q\rvert$. That's because:

- Increasing $\delta$ past some point demonstrably decreases security. E.g. for $k=3072$ (which would give about 128-bit symmetric security) and $δ=1912$ we'd have $\min(p,q)<2^{161}$ and [Lentra's ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) would likely allow to pull that factor of $n$.
- Simple arguments that increasing $\delta$ improves security are flawed.
- $\delta=0$ is believed fine.
- The historical reason to introduce a lower bound for $\lvert p-q\rvert$ is that Fermat factorization has cost about proportional to $(p-q)^2/n$ times some polynomial in $k$, thus $\lvert p-q\rvert$ must not be too small. It was jumped from that fact to the conclusion that it's needed to specify an explicit minimum $\lvert p-q\rvert$, even though it's demonstrably enough to specify that $p$ and $q$ are chosen independently and roughly uniformly among primes in some interval like $[2^{(k-1)/2},2^{k/2})$ to insure Fermat factorization is hopeless, whenever $k$ is large enough to resist [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (or [PPMPQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#More_large_primes), which was long known in 1998 when the disputable decision was inked in ANS X9.31).

As requested in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/205035) I'll nevertheless assume there's some reason to specify $\delta$, and that increasing $\delta$ increases security in some domain. In order not to contradict the fact in the first bullet point above, I'll assume $0\le\delta\le\alpha\,k+\beta$ for some reals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha\in[0,1)$. Under such hypothesis, it makes sense to define $\kappa=k+\delta$, and use that as the security parameter.

We could define RSA key generation for constant odd integer $e>1$ as: on input $1^\kappa$

1. In polynomial time, choose integers $k$ and $\delta$ with $\kappa=k+\delta$ and $0\le\delta\le\alpha k+\beta$ (fail if that's impossible); suitable ways include $\delta\gets\left\lfloor\frac\alpha2\kappa\right\rfloor$ and $k\gets\kappa-\delta$.
2. Choose $p$ uniformly randomly among primes $p$ in $[2^{(k-1)/2},2^{k/2})$ with $\gcd(p-1,e)=1$
3. Choose $q$ uniformly randomly among primes $q$ in $[2^{(k-1)/2},2^{k/2})$ with $\gcd(q-1,e)=1$ and $2^\delta<\lvert p-q\rvert$.
4. Compute $n\gets p\,q$ and $d\gets e^{-1}\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$, output public key $(n,e)$ and private key $(n,d)$.

It's believable that: for any valid choice of $e$ in this key generation algorithm, for any polynomial $P$, there exists no Probabilistic Polynomial Time algorithm that when $\kappa$ grows breaks RSA encryption with non-vanishing probability within time $P(\kappa)$.

That plausible conjecture is demonstrably¹ implied by a commonly held and simpler form of the RSA conjecture for fixed/small public exponent, which removes step (1.), replaces the condition $2^\delta<\lvert p-q\rvert$ with $p\ne q$ in step (3.), and uses $k$ where there's $\kappa$. We have no proof the conjectures are equivalent, but no compelling reason to believe otherwise, thus many practitioners and most theoreticians use the simpler conjecture².

---

¹ Proof sketch: we assume there exists an $e$ and algorithm $\mathcal A$ that breaks RSA encryption with non-vanishing probability within time $P(\kappa)$ when using the RSA key generation with $2^\delta<\lvert p-q\rvert$. We use $\mathcal A$ to build an algorithm $\mathcal A'$ invoking $\mathcal A$ as a subprogram, which for the same $e$ breaks RSA encryption with some probability within time $P'(k)$ when using the RSA key generation with $p\ne q$. The probability is non-vanishing because $p$ and $q$ meet the condition insuring $\mathcal A$ works with a probability that we can lower-bound and is non-vanishing. We can establish $P'$ from $P$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and that $P'$ is still a polynomial. $\alpha<1$ comes into play.

² Often the condition $p\ne q$ is removed too, which introduces the possibility that decryption fails. That occurs for a vanishing proportion of generated keys, but some definitions of a cipher have no exclusion for such corner case, which is why we keep $p\ne q$.