# What does the notation $1^n$ stand for?

Tags: notation

I'm seeing this all over my Katz and Lindell book and I don't see where they introduced it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the expression $1^n$ mean as a function argument?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/7852/what-does-the-expression-1n-mean-as-a-function-argument) and also of [What do $0^n$ and $1^n$ mean in cryptography?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/what-do-0n-and-1n-mean-in-cryptography)