# what is the notation of nth power of 1?

Tags: notation

when reading theoretical materials, it is often seen that "a common input 1^n..." what does it mean? Are there any similar questions and answers previously in  StackExchange?

Comment: There is a dupe for this.... Search security parameter

Comment: 1. [Why does key generation take an input 1k, and how do I represent it in practice?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8174/18298) 2. [What does the expression 1n mean as a function argument?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/7852/18298) 3. ["Power of one" as input to functions of a cryptosystem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/61703/18298)

Comment: As far as I know. $1^n$ is just an $n-$bit string of $1$'s and it is input to indicatte you are trying to input the security parameter $n$.